# Prawn keep bounding_box from overlapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am using a column_box in Prawn. It works well, but overlaps a bounding_box I'm using at the bottom for a footer.

How do I keep it from overlapping, but not adjust the height of the bounding box?

I can explain more about why I don't want to adjust the height, but I don't think its relevant to this question. Here is my code:

```
def test_section
  column_box([0,cursor], :columns => 2, :width => 396) do
    text ("This is text" * 10 + "This is too\n") * 25
    stroke_color (50,0,50,0)
    stroke_bounds
  end

  bounding_box [margin_box.left, margin_box.bottom + 72], :width => bounds.width, :height => 72 do
    font "Helvetica" do
      stroke_color (0,0,100,0)
      stroke_bounds
      text "And here's a sexy footer", :size => 16
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you,
Anthony

Comment: Have any luck here? I'm chasing a similar solution.

Comment: Me too. I am stuck with the bounding box at my footer.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem and have found a solution. if you give your column_box a max height, it will stop it flowing into the footer. Not sure how to restrict it to just the last page though, but I have the footer on every page (done with the "repeat :all" around the bounding_box).

```
    column_box([0,cursor], :columns => 2, :width => 396, :height => bounds.height - 80) do
        text ("This is text" * 10 + "This is too\n") * 25
        stroke_bounds
      end

    repeat :all do
      bounding_box [margin_box.left, margin_box.bottom + 72], :width => bounds.width, :height => 72 do
        font "Helvetica" do
          stroke_bounds
          text "And here's a sexy footer", :size => 16
        end
      end
    end
```

If you're not using a column_box, put your page content in a bounding_box with a height restriction.

```
bounding_box([bounds.left, bounds.top], :width  => bounds.width, :height => bounds.height - 80) do
  #page content
end
```

Cheers,
Dave